# specialrule with longtable and arydshln packages problem

Tags: longtable, booktabs, arydshln

When I use specialrule with longtable, there is a white vertical line in the last row.

I have tested, if I don't use `arydshln` packages, it is good. (But I want to dashed line, so I need to add arydshln)

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{green}
\rowcolors{1}{gray}{gray}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c}
    \specialrule{10pt}{0pt}{0pt}
    XXX  & XXX  & XXXXXXX \\
    \hline
    XXXX  & XXX & XXXXXXX \\
    \hline
    XXXXX  & XXX& XXX\\
    \hline
    XXX & XXXXX  & XXXXX \\
    \hline
    XXXXX & XXX & XXX \\
    \hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The example can be further simplified by removing the code related to the `xcolor` package. Apart from that, there seems to be an interaction between the `specialrule` command and the `arydshln` as you can get the desired result by removing one of them.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to modify one line.

```
\specialrule{10pt}{-10pt}{0pt}
```

The first parameter of the *\specialrule* means the thickness of the line, and the second indicates to the starting point of the connected vertical line. The starting point has been raised by thickness, so you have to lower it again.